# How to delete inactive jobs older than 6months in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have 2000 plus jobs in my dev-jenkins,I want to remove inactive job older than 6 months in Jenkins and also there workspace which is present on different slave.

Jenkins version using- 1.580.3

Thanks in advance.

Ayush

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no official solution to do that (= plugins or native Jenkins functionality).

You can find a Groovy script here which delete the inactive workspaces:
http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/automated-deletion-of-workspaces-td3799739.html

Another Groovy script to clean the workspaces (to be updated because it's actually checking the remaining free space):
https://gist.github.com/rb2k/8372402

You can schedule a maintenance job on all your slaves to launch on of these two scripts.

There is also the Jenkins [Workspace Cleanup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) plugin which can clean the workspace before or after the build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest the plugin to 'shelve' the unused job, so you can restore in future:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shelve+Project+Plugin